# Angular $compile service sensitive to white space?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I ran into this problem today where in an app I'm working on I have a bunch of links in a directive that need updating and using the $compile service within my linking function proved an easy fix. (It is not the best fix, but that's for another day.)

Anyway, my links were getting all messed up, but after deleting a single space from within a {{var| filter}} statement, everything was fixed! I can't figure this one out, but it seems specific to element attributes (given my tests compiling other HTML elements).

Here's a working example that demonstrates the problem: http://jsbin.com/IRogUxA/10/edit. (Forgive the wonky/contrived directive definition--it's the evolution of many experiments today!)

Is this a bug? Or indicative of an error-prone way of approaching the problem? Both? Any idea of what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the html that you ar compiling. You have this:

```
var temp1 = $compile('<a href={{isolateVar|toDate:false}}>A LINK THAT WORKS</a>')(scope);
var temp2 = $compile('<a href={{isolateVar| toDate:false}}>A LINK THAT DOES NOT</a>')(scope);
```

The `href` does not have quotes, so with the space, the href attribute will have a value of `{{isolateVar|`

Simply add quotes to the `href` so that it picks up the whole value you're wanting

```
var temp1 = $compile('<a href="{{isolateVar|toDate:false}}">A LINK THAT WORKS</a>')(scope);
var temp2 = $compile('<a href="{{isolateVar| toDate:false}}">A LINK THAT DOES NOT</a>')(scope);
```